# PHP form submit success message inserts unwanted number after message

Tags: php, forms

Created a php form with a success message that appears just below the Submit button upon successful mission.  After adding some additional code in the php to create an email confirmation, I'm now noticing that a number "1" has been inserted in the line after my success message - see below:

[image]

Any ideas on how to make that number 1 go away?  Code below:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$human = $_POST['human'];
$from = 'From: Page Name'; 
$to = 'email@mysite.com';  
$subject = 'Service Inquiry';
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Company: $company\n   
Message:\n $message";

// Confirmation email.
$conf_subject = 'Your recent inquiry';

$conf_sender = 'MY SITE <no-reply@mysite.com>';

$msg =  $_POST['name'] . ",\n\nThank you for your recent inquiry. A member of 
our team will respond to your message as soon as possible.\n\nThanks,\n\nMy 
Company Team";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
   if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $phone != '' && $message != '') {
       if ($human == '4') {              
           if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
           echo '<p>Thanks for your inquiry, we will get back to you as soon 
                 as we can&#33;</p>';
           echo (mail ($email, $conf_subject, $msg, 'From: ' . $conf_sender 
           ));
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again&#33;</p>'; 
    } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly&#33;</p>';
    }
    } else {
        echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields&#33;</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 echo (mail ($email, $conf_subject, $msg, 'From: ' . $conf_sender ));
```

This code is causing the echo, its echoing 1 as the mail() function is returning true. I'm not sure why you're echoing the mail function here any way, just remove the echo and all is good.

Comment: Seems to be a trend for this question

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
echo (mail ($email, $conf_subject, $msg, 'From: ' . $conf_sender));
```

You are echoing out the result of your call to the mail function. Since the mail was successfully handed over to the server it returns true. When you echo out a boolean `true` it gets converted to an integer which is `1`. That's why you see that in your code.

Remove the `echo` to remove the `1` from being displayed in your output.

Comment: I can only guess its because you simply gave the same answer as mine after I had posted?

Comment: It was more or less simultaneous. And definitely not wrong.

Comment: It's defiantly not wrong as you give the exact same info as mine, I can only guess it was downvoted as my answer was first, I've seen it a lot on SO where people just repeat one of the other answers to gain rep and they get down voted (not saying you've done that but would explain the down vote)

Comment: @Yvette i know, John asked why it was downvoted and that was the only reason I could think off because like mentioned it has the same (correct) answer as mine

Comment: Better explanation in this answer.  The others add to the stackoverflow soup.

Answer (score -1):

That is because of this code:

```
echo (mail ($email, $conf_subject, $msg, 'From: ' . $conf_sender ));
```

You "echo" the result of the mail function. "1" is equal to "true" on mail sending success.

Comment: Thanks guys, so literally just remove the "echo" from that line and it should work?  Sorry I'm new to php and cobbling together what I can from tutorials, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just remove "echo". But you can handle the result of "mail" function. For example, if (mail(...)) {echo "ok";} else { echo "Mail error";}

Comment: Typically, don't echo the boolean result of a function but check if it is true or false, and then do something (like displaying an error message if the function failed) if it is true or false